# Retrofit -u username:password fields and scopes array

Tags: android, curl, oauth, github-api, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to build a Android Github app but I am having troubles retrieving the token from https://api.github.com/authorizations

I know how to do the request with curl with the command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: Application/json" -u "username:password" -d '{"scopes": ["user","repo","gist","notifications","repo","repo:status"],"note":"GithubViewer Android App","client_id":"xxx","client_secret":"yyyy"}' "https://api.github.com/authorizations"
```

I am having troubles knowing how to set up the Scopes array and the -u authentication field. I've tried in the command line using "Authentication: Basic username:password" but that does not work either :(

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
RequestInterceptor interceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                   request.addHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + username + ":" + password);
           }
        };

 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
         .setEndpoint(GithubClient.API_URL)
          .setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
          .build();
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post what you did?

Comment: this is what I did. First I modified my request to send a @Body with the request. Them I made a class that would serialize to whatever was needed for that request.
https://gist.github.com/fnk0/f3ef3d5d15d72bff3fb2

Comment: I figured out how to do it yesterday. I missed the @Body annotation back there and had to create a basic auth. Thanks! Did you finish your app? I can review it 8D

Comment: @Atieh my app was for an Online Android course with Udacity. I turned the app in and passed the course but the app is not yet ready for any kind of production phase. (I do wish to keep developing it and maybe have it ready by the end of the summer)

Comment: sounds like a plan. What are planning to use for testing? Testing is usually my weak point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Retrofit, but I am spotting something that might cause your problems. You are supplying the username:password as plain text in the Authentication header, it should however be encoded using Base64 encoding.

```
String str = "username:password";
String base64EncodedUsernamePassword;

try {
    base64EncodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encode(str.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // Weird, no UTF-8 encoding found?
}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! I figured out my problem at the end... I was trying to send UrlFormEncoded data to the github api and they only accept plain json objects on the post request.